# Changing column name with Python in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, concatenation, data-analysis

I am trying to figure out why my column name isn't changing. The column name is 0 and I want to change it to motorsport. How do I go about doing this?

Below is what I have tried:

```
data=pd.read_csv("Automobile.csv")
motorsport = ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']
motorsport = pd.DataFrame(motorsport)
data2 = pd.concat([data,motorsport], axis=1, sort=False)
data2 = data2.rename(columns={'0': 'motorsport'})
```

Comment: Are you sure its `'0'` and not `0`

Comment: You should provide `data2.columns`

Answer (score 0):

```
motorsport.columns = ['motorsport']
```

You should put this code after converting list to dataframe(3rd row), then you can concatenate two dataframes.